# Highchart dual y-axes with same base and smaller tickinterval

Tags: highcharts

I want to decrease the tickinterval of primary y-axes in my dual axes chart so that the columns height could increase. Chart is working well but due to high intervals, columns height is getting small. The data is dynamic and will remain the same as I have used in the example on jsfiddle.
Please see the jsfiddle i have created for this.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/mr6dyh94/2/`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `alignTicks` property to false. In API documentation we can read:

> tickInterval: number
>
> ...
>
> If the chart has multiple axes, the alignTicks option may interfere with the tickInterval setting.

```
chart: {
    alignTicks: false
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dcpz592x/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks

Comment: Thank you. But i have tried that thing also. actually i want to make those columns little more longer in height. But both y-axes should have same base starting at 0

Comment: So, in this case, you can manually set the position of the ticks: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cjdsLxkf/

Comment: Thank you so much @ppotaczek. It seems to work for me. I am testing with different cases. Once again thank you so much. You saved me.